# ionic InAppBrowser Events Not Firing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm Using ionic cordova in-app-browser plugin

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser){
      const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.sample.com'_self',{location:'no'}); /*3*/

this.browser.on('loadstart', event => {
    alert('loadstart event'); // not fired
    });
    this.browser.on('loaderror', event => {
      alert(' error'); // not fired
      });
    this.browser.on('exit', event => {
      alert('exit event'); // not fired
    });
}
```

But loadstart, loaderror, exit events not working.
Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

Use target `"_blank"` instead of `"_self"`, like:

```js
const browser = this.iab.create(
'https://www.sample.com',
'_blank',
{location:'no'}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest ionic version then following is the way in which each event is called for inappbrowser:

```
openInAppBrowser(){
const options:any = {
      closebuttoncolor: "#ffffff",
      lefttoright: 'yes',
      hideurlbar: 'yes',
      fullscreen: 'yes',
      hardwareback: 'no',
      toolbarcolor: '#145a7b',
      zoom: 'no',
      useWideViewPort: 'no',
      hidenavigationbuttons: 'yes',
      footer: 'no',
      message: "Hello",
      toolbar : 'no',
      location:'no'
    }

 let browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', options); 

 browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(async event =>{
     //your logic goes in here....
});

 browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(async event =>{
     //your logic goes in here....
});

 browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(async event =>{
     //your logic goes in here....
});

 browser.on('beforeload').subscribe(async event =>{
     //your logic goes in here....
});

 browser.on('message').subscribe(async event =>{
     //your logic goes in here....
});
}
```

Comment: Implementation of message event in inAppBrowser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357650/15975062

Answer (score -1):

First Check platform.ready() Event After countinue your process.

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser){
platform.ready().then(() => {
  if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {

//Do your process

const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.sample.com'_self',{location:'no'}); /*3*/

this.browser.on('loadstart', event => {
    alert('loadstart event'); // not fired
    });
    this.browser.on('loaderror', event => {
      alert(' error'); // not fired
      });
    this.browser.on('exit', event => {
      alert('exit event'); // not fired
    });

    });
   }
  }
```